# Count the number of months per item group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a table with ItemID, Qty, and OrderDate

I am only querying results that have an order date of between next month (Current Month + 1) and 11 months after that.

I am trying to write a Query that gets me the SUM of the QTY by ItemID, and the COUNT of months that exists for each ItemID.

I can get so far as getting a result set that looks like this:

```
ITEMID  Qty    TMonth   TYear
01.0002 392.00    1      2019
01.0002 392.00    2      2019
01.0002 392.00    3      2019
01.0002 784.00    4      2019
01.0002 784.00    5      2019
01.0002 392.00    6      2019
01.0002 784.00    7      2019
01.0002 392.00    8      2019
01.0002 392.00    9      2019
```

I get this by grouping on ITEMID, MONTH(OrderDate), YEAR(OrderDate) and it shows the total for each month/year.  There are a total of 9 months in this example.  though, you would see this repeated for each item, and its associated month/year, which if an order exists, could be 1 through 11.

I need a result set that looks like:

```
ITEMID      Qty        MnthCount
01.0002     4704.00     9
A0-B1002    3300.00     2
ZX-YT12       50.00     7
```

I figure there has to be some Window Function or something I can use.  Is there a way of doing this, or do I need to resort to Sub-Selects or some sort of Outer Apply?

Comment: What's the underlying data look like?  Would you share your query?

Comment: Well, its pretty simple, ItemID, Qty and OrderDate Sample data would look like:


AX09-1     5     3/15/2018
Z7-HJk     4     3/01/2018

And so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like this ?

```
---drop table test 
create table test 
(ITEMID varchar(20),
Qty decimal(10,2),
TMonth  int, 
TYear int)
insert into test values 
('01.0002',392.00,1,2019),
('01.0002',392.00,2,2019),
('01.0002',392.00,3,2019),
('01.0002',784.00,4,2019),
('01.0002',784.00,5,2019),
('01.0002',392.00,6,2019),
('01.0002',784.00,7,2019),
('01.0002',392.00,8,2019),
('01.0002',392.00,9,2019),
('A0-B1002',300.00,8,2019),
('A0-B1002',3000.00,9,2019),
('ZX-YT12',5.00,1,2019),
('ZX-YT12',5.00,2,2019),
('ZX-YT12',5.00,3,2019),
('ZX-YT12',5.00,4,2019),
('ZX-YT12',5.00,5,2019),
('ZX-YT12',5.00,6,2019),
('ZX-YT12',20.00,7,2019)

select ITEMID,sum(Qty) as Qty, count(TMonth) as MnthCount
from test  group by ITEMID
/*
ITEMID               Qty                                     MnthCount
-------------------- --------------------------------------- -----------
01.0002              4704.00                                 9
A0-B1002             3300.00                                 2
ZX-YT12              50.00                                   7
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

For the future, it makes it much easier to answer such questions if you include some sample data (few dozen rows) into the question together with your expected result that is based on this sample data.

---

There are many ways to do it. Here is one variant.

Since you need one row per `ItemID` in the result set we should group by `ItemID`. Sum of `Qty` is simple.

To count the months do a bit of transformation first.

```
DATEDIFF(month, '2001-01-01', OrderDate)
```

returns the number of months that passed since some anchor date. You can choose any other 1st day of the month instead of `2001-01-01`. `COUNT(DISTINCT)` would count all unique values.

The final query:

```
SELECT
    ITEMID
    ,SUM(Qty) AS TotalQty
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(month, '2001-01-01', OrderDate)) AS MonthCount
FROM
    YourTable
WHERE
    OrderDate >= @StartDate
    AND OrderDate < @EndDate
GROUP BY
    ITEMID
;
```